# Replace string starting with in between two lines using bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Is there a way to use sed to replace starting of the string in the entire file without using a loop?

For example, my source data is the following:

```
str_address: 123 main street
str_desc: Apt3
str_desc: 2nd floor
str_city: new york
str_desc: mailing address
```

Now, the file will have thousands of addresses, but I want anytime "**`str_desc`**" appears after "**`str_address`**" and before "**`str_city`**" to be replaced with "**`str_address`**", however any "**`str_desc`**" that appears after **`str_city`** to remain unchanged.

Desired output:

```
str_address: 123 main street
str_address: Apt3
str_address: 2nd floor
str_city: new york
str_desc: mailing address
```

I can extract this info with,

```
cat file | awk '/str_city/{f=0} f; /str_address/{f=1}'
```

which gives

```
str_desc: Apt3
str_desc: 2nd floor
```

But I am having trouble changing the first "**`str_desc`**" to "**`str_address`**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have the complete solution in your `awk` extraction code:

```
awk '/str_city/{f=0} f; /str_address/{f=1}'
```

The idea is to:

- turn the flag on when you see `str_address`.
- turn the flag off when you see `str_city`.
- replace `str_desc` with `str_address` if the flag is on.

That's basically (in readable form, and the order is important):

```
awk '
    $1 == "str_address:"           { flag = 1 }
    $1 == "str_desc:" && flag == 1 { $1 = "str_address:" }
    $1 == "str_city:"              { flag = 0 }
                                   { print }
    ' < inputFile >outputFile
```

Here's a transcript showing it in action:

```
pax$ echo '
     str_address: 123 main street
     str_desc: Apt3
     str_desc: 2nd floor
     str_city: new york
     str_desc: mailing address
     ' | awk '
         $1 == "str_address:"           { flag = 1 }
         $1 == "str_desc:" && flag == 1 { $1 = "str_address:" }
         $1 == "str_city:"              { flag = 0 }
                                        { print }'

str_address: 123 main street
str_address: Apt3
str_address: 2nd floor
str_city: new york
str_desc: mailing address
```

And, of course, a minified version:

```
awk '$1=="str_address:"{f=1}$1=="str_desc:"&&f==1{$1="str_address:"}$1=="str_city:"{f=0}{print}' < inputFile >outputFile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an address range in sed:

```
$ sed '/str_address/,/str_city/s/str_desc/str_address/' infile
str_address: 123 main street
str_address: Apt3
str_address: 2nd floor
str_city: new york
str_desc: mailing address
```

This leaves all the `str_desc` outside of the `/str_address/,/str_city/` range untouched, and substitutes the others with `str_address` (that's the  `s/str_desc/str_address/` part).

Comment: but that range is greedy. Isnt it??

Comment: @sjsam No, it works with multiple blocks. Try with the example input duplicated, for example.

Comment: @sjsam It can't be greedy, sed doesn't know what comes later when looking at a line.