# Replace/Remove lines between two other lines in Bash

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed

I have this file which is a **Linux Device Tree**:

```
# Other content
...

&uart3 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_uart3>;
    status = "okay";
};

# Other content
...
```

At first I wanted to extract lines between `&uart3` and `};` which is the UART3 node, with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^&uart3/,${p;/^};/q}' uart3.dts
```

Output is:

```
&uart3 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_uart3>;
    status = "okay";
};
```

My problem, is how to remove all lines between `&uart3` and `};` , or is there a way to replace them with other content.

I read the `awk` solution about detecting a match and raising certain flag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030861/replace-string-starting-with-in-between-two-lines-using-bash).
But I don't understand how to achieve this.

I'm not parsing the Device Tree here so no need for dtc library,

I'm handling the file as a text file only.

Since this gonna be ran into a Yocto recipe, the solution can be in `Python` as well.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what problem you encountered trying to follow the awk approach? What did you try to do, and how did it fail? (Also, which version of awk are you trying to target? POSIX-standard awk? mawk? gawk?)

Comment: (In general, "how can I do this across _any_ language?" questions are prone to being considered too broad to be on-topic; asking about a specific problem you had doing this in sed in one question, a specific problem you had doing this in awk in another question, &c. would avoid that).

Comment: I want this in Bash or Python, I already detailed that I need to remove/modify any number of lines between two lines that I can get using two patters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variant of what seems the most frequent question I answer, lol

```
$: cat file
# Other content
...

&uart3 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_uart3>;
    status = "okay";
};

# Other content
...

$: cat replacement.txt
   This is what I want there instead.
   I just stuck it over here in this other file.

$: cat tst
sed '/^&uart3 {/,/^};/{
  /^&uart3 {/{ p; r replacement.txt
             }
  /^};/!d;
}' file

$: ./tst
# Other content
...

&uart3 {
   This is what I want there instead.
   I just stuck it over here in this other file.
};

# Other content
...
```

`/^&uart3 {/,/^};/{` opens a block on any line in the matched range from `^&uart3 {` to the next `^};`
The next bit has a gotcha - don't put anything on the same line after a filename.

```
      /^&uart3 {/{ p; r replacement.txt
                 }
```

That says if the line we're looking at is the `^&uart3 {` then open a block -
first `p`rint it, then `r`ead in the contents of `replacement.txt`.
You have to close the block on the next line in most implementations, though, so it doesn't think the curly is part of the file name and break the syntax.

`/^};/!d;` says for the rest of the block, *unless* (`!`) it's the closing curly, just `d`elete it.

---

### #edit

If you want to do it without a file -

```
$: cat tst
sed '/^&uart3 {/,/^};/{
  /^&uart3 {/{ p; a\
   This is what I want there instead.\
   There is no other file.
             }
  /^};/!d;
}' file

$: ./tst
# Other content
...

&uart3 {
   This is what I want there instead.
   There is no other file.
};

# Other content
...
```

c.f. https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands
It's all there. :)

Comment: And what if I want to do it without a file ?

Comment: Edited. Not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

In native bash:

```sh
retrieve_only_section() {
  local start end reading
  start=$1; end=$2; reading=0
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line = $start ]]; then
      reading=1
    elif [[ $line = $end ]]; then
      reading=0
      printf '%s\n' "$line"
      continue
    fi
    (( reading )) && printf '%s\n' "$line"
  done
}
```

...and `retrieve_only_section '&uart3 {' '};' <yourfile` will retrieve only the section.

Similarly, one can just replace `(( reading )) && printf '%s\n' "$line"` with `(( reading )) || printf '%s\n' "$line"` to print only things *outside* the section.

To *replace* the section, one might use:

```sh
replace_section() {
  local start end replacement in_section
  start=$1; end=$2; replacement=$3; in_section=0
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    if (( ! in_section )) && [[ $line = $start ]]; then
      in_section=1
    elif (( in_section )) && [[ $line = $end ]]; then
      in_section=0
      printf '%s\0' "$replacement"
      continue
    fi
    (( in_section )) || printf '%s\n' "$line"
  done
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me how your second code will edit the &uart3 block and change it with something and put it all back to the main file.

Comment: @BelHadjSalemTALEL, it's a pipeline. Same as you could run `sed <foo > foo.new && mv foo.new foo`, you get the same thing with `replace_section foo bar "$new_value" <foo >foo.new && mv foo.new foo`

Comment: @BelHadjSalemTALEL, keep in mind, `sed -i` and `awk -i` both do the same "write to a temporary file and then rename over the original" thing. There basically _are_ no standard tools that rewrite a file in-place, because the practice is inherently memory-intensive and hazardous (when the size of the input stream is not known a priori; if it doesn't fit into a single `write()` syscall's boundary, one can't guarantee anything even remotely like atomicity -- and if you want to keep the old data around to read you can't truncate it until you're _done_ reading it, so output needs somewhere to go).

Comment: Running both examples didn't work, `retrieve_only_section` retrieved the block without the `};`, and `replace_section` replaces from `&uart3` until the last line before `};` with $replacement and then leaves `};`

Comment: @BelHadjSalemTALEL, see the 2nd one working in the online sandbox at at https://ideone.com/fvhLkm. Similarly, if you want to show me that something _doesn't_ work, it would be helpful if you provided a sandbox link so I can see that with my own eyes.

Comment: Now I understand after seeing the execution

Answer (score 1):

If `ed` is available/acceptable.

```
printf '%s\n' '/^&uart3 {$/+1;/^};$/-1c'  foo .  ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

---

Output

```
# Other content
...

&uart3 {
foo
};

# Other content
...
```

---

Or use an array to store the new data/input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input_data=(
'  foo'
'  bar'
'  baz'
'  more'
'  qux'
)

printf '%s\n' '/^&uart3 {$/+1;/^};$/-1c'  "${input_data[@]}" .  ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

---

Output

```
# Other content
...

&uart3 {
  foo
  bar
  baz
  more
  qux
};

# Other content
...
```

---

Or use a separate file for the new input/data

`input_file.txt`

```
the
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over
the
lazy
dog
```

Then

```
printf '%s\n' '/^&uart3/+1;/^};/-1d' '-1r input_file.txt' ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

---

Output

```
# Other content
...

&uart3 {
the
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over
the
lazy
dog
};

# Other content
...
```

---

- Change `Q` to `w` if you're ok with the output and *in-place* editing of the `file.txt` will occur.
- Remove the `,p` to silence the output.

Comment: ed not found in my build system which is `Yocto` , I up voted your answer because it worked generally on my host machine. But I need other solution rather than `ed` .

Comment: Ok, sad to hear `ed` is not available, hopefully the `awk` masters will come to the rescue! :-)

Answer (score -1):

##### A) remove the lines with sed

```
sed '5,7d' file
```

`5,7` is a range [lines to delete] this are inclusive, meaning is going to delete line 5,6,7. `d` argument is to delete in sed. *Taking your example this is going to return the following:*

```
&uart3 {
};
```

##### B) replace ONE line with sed

```
sed '5s/[a-z].*/stringToReplace/' file
```

`5` selects the number line[5] the `s` for replace string, `[a-z]` is for selecting any letter in lowercase, in this case: `pinctrl`. `.*` is for selecting [the whole line]. **output**:

```
&uart3 {
  stringToReplace
  pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_uart3>;
  status = "okay";
};
```

##### C) replace all lines with `sed` from another text file

```
sed '5,+2d;4r replace.txt' file
```

if you have another file with TEXT then use `r` ARGUMENT replace.txt.
`5,+2d` selects the line number `5`. `+2` selects two lines after 5, meaning, 5,6,7.`d` deletes the lines. `;` is for adding another `sed` command[like pipes]. `4r` means, selects line number 4. `r` means replace with a text file, in this case `replace.txt`. *output*

```
&uart3 {
  replace = line 5
  replace = line 6
  replace = line 7
};
```

##### You need to know the number of lines to be removed:

```
grep -n "pinctrl-\|status" file
```

`-n` returns the number of lines. `\|` this is for multiples arguments with grep. `'example1\|example2\|exmple3'` --> *returns*:

[image]